# How many times can you use hero ability?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

For hero abilities bought with XP is there a limit to how many times they can be used?

For example can Diala use her Force Adept: 1 strain: Use while you or a friendly figure is performing and attack or attribute test. That figure may reroll 1 die.
to let a player rerolling dice?

Or will Weapon Expert: 1 strain: use while attacking to gain Pierce 1 and apply +2 Accuracy to the attack results. make Fenn be able to shoot accross the map and just pay with strain/health for whatever accuracy he is missing?

Answer (score 1):

From pg. 2 of the Rules Reference:

> If an ability is “used,” it can be triggered multiple times each round, but it can only be triggered once per timing instance. For example, an ability that says, “Use while attacking to apply +1H to the attack results,” can only be triggered once during each attack.